# CSS Only Dropdown - Popout Not Positioned in IE/Firefox

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/QKThn/1/

The drop down menu works fine in Chrome but the positioning of the nested UL (the list that pops down on :hover) isn't directly below the parent LI in Internet Explorer or Firefox.  In both IE and FF, the nested UL menu hugs the left of the entire NAV rather than its parent LI.

Any idea what I'm missing?

CSS:

```
nav {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    line-height: 120px;
}


nav ul {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}


nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

nav a, nav a:visited {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #005f99;
}

nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #7fafcc;
    /*border-bottom: 2px solid #5cbc51;*/
}

nav li.current a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #7fafcc;
    /*border-bottom: 2px solid #5cbc51;*/
}

nav li ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    background-color: #005f99;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 999;
}

nav ul ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

nav ul ul li:hover {
    background: #22284f;
}

nav ul ul li a, nav ul ul li a:visited {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover, nav ul ul li a:active {
        color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
}
nav ul ul li {
    line-height: 40px;
}


nav ul ul li { border-color: #35b5eb; }
nav ul ul li+li { border-color: #0acf67; }
nav ul ul li+li+li { border-color: #f2c13f; }
nav ul ul li+li+li+li { border-color: #a5c950; }
nav ul ul li+li+li+li+li { border-color: #ab50c9; }
nav ul ul li+li+li+li+li+li { border-color: #eb5b4c; }
```

HTML:

```
  <nav>  <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="" title="">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="">about us</a>

                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Our Mission</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">History &amp; Impact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Financials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Staff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Board Members</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Careers & Jobs</a></li>
                    </ul>

            </li>

            <li><a href="" title="">get involved</a></li>           
            <li><a href="" title="">stores</a>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Our Mission</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">History &amp; Impact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Financials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Staff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Board Members</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Careers & Jobs</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="" title="">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `left: 0;` to `nav ul ul`

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/QKThn/3/

CSS

```
nav ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 29px;
left: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 0 5px;
background-color: #005f99;
width: 200px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Right on the money, thanks!! =D ...you wouldn't believe how long I was looking at this unable to find a solution.  6 minutes until I can accept your answer!

Comment: You're welcome. It's always the smallest thing that needs to be changed :D